What is the highest number of points attained by a player in the WTA rankings?
AFAICT when a player in either ATP or WTA rankings gets about 10000 points, it is a sign of a very good season.
In the ATP rankings the highest number of ranking points ever is 16950, reached by Novak Djokovic in June 2016.1
What is the record for the most points in the WTA rankings?

1This is mentioned in the Wikipedia article List of ATP number 1 ranked singles tennis players (current revision):
"Djokovic also holds the record of 16,950 ranking points on 6 June 2016, the most ATP points ever accumulated by any player."
A reference given there is an article on the ATP website. It is no longer available, but it can be found in the Wayback Machine.
This claim can be found also in various other places.

This answer a community wiki - feel free to update or improve it.
Several sources list as the highest number of reputation points 13615 points of Serena Williams in June 2013. This was after winning 2013 French Open.
It is worth mentioning that the structure of the WTA Tour and the ranking system was changed in the 2009 season.
Sources

Tennis365: The 7 players with the most ranking points since 2009: Iga Swiatek already at No 2
WTA_Insider on X/Twitter: "Iga Swiatek will finish with 11,085 #WTA ranking points.
Since the WTA Rankings were introduced, only Serena Williams recorded more points, most recently in June 2013 (13,615 points).
It is the 2nd most year-end ranking points earned, behind Williams’ 2013 total of 13,260."
tennis.com: Iga Swiatek now has the most ranking points for any woman since Serena Williams in 2015
Sportskeeda: Iga Swiatek becomes only the second player after Serena Williams to reach 11,000 points in WTA rankings
r/tennis: Iga Swiatek is the second player after Serena Williams to reach 11000 WTA ranking points

